# npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error keep showing

Tags: angularjs, npm, generator, tar

[image]

this error comes not only generator-angular, but also any other generators..

vmware + ubuntu14 + nvm

I installed gulp package, and adjust my $PATH.

also tried 'npm cache clean'

BUT nothing works for me..

somehow I made good one but never made again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had problems with this when using npm on a ubuntu 14 instance running using virtualbox.

From what I remember I think it has to do with the repository sources

Try installing node using these instructions.

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installing-node.js-via-package-manager

Comment: I used nvm for installing npm. You mean install your link package, not  nvm?